# Error with a span with role="textbox" having an aria-placeholder attribute

Tags: html, css

```css
.comment-box2 {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;

    outline: none;

    min-height: 40px;
    line-height: 20px;

    padding-left: 8px;
    background-color:#F5FFFA;
    border-radius:15px;
    border: 1px solid #708090;
    display:inline-block;
    width:330px;

}
```

```html
<span class="comment-box2" role="textbox" id="comment" contenteditable aria-placeholder="Write a Comment..."></span>
```

here the span appears as an textbox but the aria-placeholder attribute doesnt seem to work at all.is this not allowed ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Screen readers read aloud the hint provided via `aria-placeholder` property only when the text box does not have a value in it. If a `value` or text is available in the text box, a screen reader announces the value instead of placeholder text. You don't see placeholder text like you would when using `placeholder` because `aria-placeholder` is meant to be read by assistive technologies like a screen reader. In your example, a screen reader will read the string "Write a Comment..." provided by `aria-placeholder`.

The `aria-placeholder` attribute is meant to simulate the HTML5 behavior of the `placeholder` attribute and make it valid within other simulated control types and roles where the HTML5 placeholder attribute is not valid. The placeholder should be visible when the control's value is an empty string such as when the control first receives focus and when users remove a previously-entered value. Instead of using `aria-placeholder`, use the semantic `<input type="text">` with a corresponding `<label>` or `<textarea>` with a `placeholder` attribute if you can.

That being said, authors should present this hint to the users only when a control doesn't have a value. This includes:

- When the control first receives the focus
- When user erases the previously entered value

To address your statement "the span appears as an textbox but the aria-placeholder attribute doesnt seem to work at all. is this not allowed?". It is "allowed" to use `aria-placeholder` for `role="textbox"` fields. The value should be a string whose value is equal to the hint provided for filling data into the text box.

Comment: @Ferris Does this help to answer your question?